# Step down from 24V to 12V to drive 12V pump causing 30V back to supply

Tags: dc-motor, step-down

This is strange situation, where main power is 24VDC from adapto. Then, I need to drive 12VDC pump and I decide to use step down module adjust to 12V and connect direcly to that pump.
The 30V DC just blowup other circuit what going on? How to fixed these?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkwkCF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is step down module and 12VDC pump that I refered to.
[image: Step down module I used]
[image]

Comment: Where does the 30V come in?  Are you measuring it somewhere?

Comment: At step down module's input. the same point as supply rail.

Comment: Turn a buck convertor round and it's a boost convertor. So when you use it to drive a motor ( = a generator) always protect the input side against overvoltage.

Comment: @user_1818839 How that happen and how to prevent this situation?

Comment: The motor acted as a generator (perhaps momentarily when you switched power off) and the converter boosted its voltage on the input. See previous comment for the usual way to prevent it.

Comment: It not transient but it continueus appear 30V input.
Seem like adaptor is just old school transformer with bridge rectifier and capacitor so it not regulate the voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the reason behind all of these nonsense. Seem like filter capacitor is dry-out so I got full rectified wave as below. With multimeter I got about 24V
[image]
When connect to module, a input cap of module filter the wave and raising average voltage to 30V. This is really  embarrassing but I hope it shown limitation of multimeter when working with frequency.